# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.ServletInputStream Error deploying on websphere

Tags: java, servlets, websphere, jersey, websphere-7

I have created a jersey web service with neatbeans using glassfish as my server, everything works fine but i have issues trying to install the same app on websphere 7.

i get this error "Error 500 An error occurred while processing request: /ibm/console/upload.do Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.ServletInputStream".

I even tried creating a simple web app and tried to deploy on websphere, again, i have the same error.

Anybody with ideas? I need your help so badly ya'll. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked the FFDC logs of the application server? It should provide more relevant information in debugging your issue.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you don't have servlet-api.jar in your WEB-INF/lib. If its there it may interfere with the one already present in websphere a trick the classloader

Comment: I do not think it is bundled with the app by default. Is there any other way to know if it is bunled apart from checking the libraries in netbeans because i checked it and it is not bundled with it.

Comment: I have bundled servlet-api.jar with the project and redeployed to websphere but i am having this error still. Any more ideas?

Comment: i have removed it but still have the same error. Do you think it's version problem?

Comment: ServletInputStream has been there for a long time, so it shouldn't be. It looks like a classloader problem. Can you try deploying it to a separate tomcat instance?

Comment: i developed and deployed it with glassfish and i'm tying to deploy with websphere which is what i am having issues with

Comment: try upgrading your websphere. Honestly, those app servers are so buggy and that's the reason I've rarely used them.

Comment: What jars are you deploying? I'd guess you're deploying another one (or more) which you shouldn't be, which is causing the classloader to look in the wrong place for dependent classes.

Comment: apart from the servlet-api, you should exclude jsp and el jars

Comment: @dbreaux, it's a jersey webservice.

Comment: Really guys, i don't know what else to do. nothing still

Comment: But which other jars are you deploying with the app? Can you list them all? If you're deploying Jersey copies of anything that WAS already provides, you are probably confusing the classloader. Worst case, you can try switching WAS to parent_last classloading, but if you can instead remove any duplicated classes, that will be safer and simpler.

Comment: @dbreaux, i also tried a simple web app and the same thing happens. Or is it having issues with sun-web.xml?

Comment: I would expect sun-web.xml to be ignored. How simple of an app are you deploying? If you're deploying no jars at all and this error is still occurring, you might need to contact IBM support afterall. That would seem like a basic installation problem. Are the WebSphere sample applications installed & working?

Comment: @dbreaux, i even ignored deploying the major applications itself and created a jsp page and the same thing happens

Answer (score 1):

I did below steps which worked for me :

1. Go to the server in console(which was stand - alone in my case i.e no DMGR)
2. Change the class loader policy to "multiple".

Comment: That's a workaround, not a solution. You still need to remove the container-specific libraries from the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I am not too late to reply to this question. The HttpServlet class can be found in the j2ee.jar. WAS does not bundle it in servlet-api.jar, the way Tomcat does it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to  bundle servlet-api.jar file in your application.

Comment: it is already bundled with the app server. You must _not_ have it bundled with the application

Comment: @Bozho, I agree with you, but I found similar issue while working JBoss. As a work around I simply bundled the jar file in war and it work. But I am still curious to know why it was happening.

Comment: if the jar is not bundled with the app server, then the app server does not conform to the spec.. :)

Comment: Well that's least likely :). But I see some dirty classloading issue here.

Comment: where do i locate the servlet-api.jar file?

Comment: I have bundled servlet-api.jar with the project and redeployed to websphere but i am having this error still. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Ololade, right now I cannot figure out your problem. will post in case I find anything.